# Merging two data.frames: new data frame creates duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames that look like this:

```
    2016-01-23 15:07:10
1                   11
2                    5
3                    4
4                    9
5                   12
6                   17
7                   16
8                   10
9                    7
10                  20
data.frame':    10 obs. of  1 variable:
$ 2016-01-23 15:07:10: chr  "11" "5" "4" "9" ...
```

The second data frame is the same, only numbers differ. When I use merge
command I become this:

```
merge(df_1,df_2,all = TRUE) 

2016-01-23 15:07:10 2016-02-16 16:33:23
1                    11                  14
2                     5                  14
3                     4                  14
4                     9                  14
5                    12                  14
6                    17                  14
7                    16                  14
8                    10                  14
9                     7                  14
10                   20                  14
11                   11                   5
12                    5                   5
13                    4                   5
14                    9                   5
15                   12                   5
16                   17                   5
17                   16                   5
18                   10                   5
19                    7                   5
20                   20                   5
[...]
```

So as you can see, the new data frame increase the total observations by 10(duplicates). 
How can I fix that?

Comment: how did u use merge? can you provide reproducible example?

Comment: merge(df_1,df_2,all = TRUE)

Comment: Ideally, you should have same column in two data.frames so that you can merge by that column. see `by =` argument in merge. If you just want to merge without that consider using `cbind`

Comment: Maybe using cbind is all you need.